# Is there any ASP.NET application to monitor online user and page view log report?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, elmah, signalr

I've recently seen [ElmahR](http://elmahr.apphb.com/) which is very useful to monitor the application's exceptions.

Is there any application like ElmahR to monitor online users and trace the user navigation.

I've seen some usefull reports in Site Log module in [DNN](http://www.dotnetnuke.com), but I want to use a stand-alone application to monitor online users and get page view reports for any asp.net application.

Comment: "monitor the application's exceptions" is different from "get page view reports for any asp.net application"

Comment: I mean that I want to see both exception log and page view log together in the same time in a panel like ElmahR. (As I mentioned, I can see it in DNN)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like real time analytics?

http://analytics.blogspot.com/2011/09/whats-happening-on-your-site-right-now.html

I think you know google real time analytics but are you searching for another solution?

Comment: Exacltly, but I can't use Google Analytics.

Comment: But why? There are lots of tools like google analytics.

http://smashinghub.com/20-best-real-time-analytic-tools.htm

Comment: The application is in local mode and it has not access to the internet.

Comment: You could use the Piwiki tool that is listed in the link by @emremp as it be loaded onto your own server.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Elmah in my 4 projects and it is one of the best monitoring tool which i feel now currently available with the market. Also the configuration of Elmah is quiet easy when compared to the others. It needs only some configurations in web.config and needs to include only the [HandleError] Attribute on to the controller, so that MVC will log error to Elmah once there is a break in the controller actions. If needed i will provide you the useful link to configure elmah.

Comment: Thanks, I know how to use and gather the log data, is there any Web UI application to show the reports?